# react-native-maps markers not displayed on map

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

My markers won't render on the map. I initially had a stateless functional component but changed to a class to use `this.forceUpdate()` and it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong? I have tested on both Android and iOS real devices. The map is showing but not the markers. Could it be that the map is appearing on top of the markers, like a `zIndex` issue? I hardcoded a `marker` there to be sure the problem isn't with my `props.markers`

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  Button,
  Container
} from 'native-base'

import selectMarkers from './markers.selector'

import { updateRegion } from './map.action'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import { toggleMenu } from '../search-page/searchPage.action'
import mapStyle from './style'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  region: state.get('map').get('region'),
  markers: selectMarkers(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onRegionChange: (region) => {
    dispatch(updateRegion(region))
  },
  onToggleMenuClick: () => {
    dispatch(toggleMenu())
  }
})

class Map extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => { })
    this.forceUpdate()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render() {
  console.log('map')
  console.log('markers', this.props.markers)
    return (
      <Container>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          region={{
            latitude: this.props.region.latitude,
            longitude: this.props.region.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: this.props.region.latitudeDelta,
            longitudeDelta: this.props.region.longitudeDelta,
          }}
        >
          {
            this.props.markers.map(marker => {
              return (
                <MapView.Marker
                  onLoad={() => this.forceUpdate()}
                  coordinate={{ latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude }}
                  title={marker.name}
                />
              )
            })}

          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{ latitude: 174.7666099, longitude: -36.8457991 }}
            title={"title"}
            description={"description"}
            onLoad={() => this.forceUpdate()}
            key={1}
          />
        </MapView>
        <Button
          small
          icon
          style={mapStyle.toggleMenuButton}
          onPress={() => this.props.onToggleMenuClick()}>
          <Icon name="sliders" size={20} color="#FFFFFF" />
        </Button>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

Map.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}

Map.propTypes = {
  region: React.PropTypes.shape({
    latitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    latitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number
  }).isRequired,
  onRegionChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onToggleMenuClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  markers: React.PropTypes.array
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Map)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    zIndex: -1
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed up your latitude and longitude.

`latitude: 174.7666099, longitude: -36.8457991` is not a point on the map.

`latitude: -36.8457991, longitude: 174.7666099` is a point on the map.

Comment: Thank you. I also did the same mistake and didn't notice.